# How to print the filename returned by askopenfilename?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

As the codes show, I wanted to print the file name.

```
def callback():
    file_name = open(askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Music File", "*.mp3")
                                                         ,("Video files", "*.mpeg")
                                                        )),'r')

    print file_name
```

It printed this line

```
<open file u'C:/Users/121794/Desktop/New folder (2)/Tonight.mp3', mode 'r' at 0x01D63C80>
```

How can I just get the filename with its extension? e.g "Tonight.mp3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the call to `open`:

```
filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Music File", "*.mp3"),
                                      ("Video files", "*.mpeg")))
```

If you want only the filename (excluding directory path), use `os.path.basename`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename('a/b/c')
'c'
```

Comment: i still can't get/understand os.path.basename('a/b/c') part

Comment: @user3817491, `a/b/c` is example path that could be returned from `askopenfilename`.

Comment: @user3817491, In other words, `filename = os.path.basename(filename)`

Answer (score 1):

```
## python 3.x
f = file_name.split("/")
print (f[-1])
```

Comment: While this might work for the given example, if you want portable code that can work on different OS, it's better to just use the built-in `os.path` or `pathlib` functions.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.